# Is it possible to pass TestNG data provider data from a test into an @aftermethod teardown

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

something like this:

```
@Test(groups = {"eventAdmin"}, dataProvider="EventAdminProvider",   
     dataProviderClass= EventAdminCurationDataproviderClass.class)
public void EventCurationclearFilter(String eventName) throws Exception {

@AfterMethod(groups={"eventAdmin"})
public void teardown(String eventName) throws Exception {
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes but not directly like with a `@Test`. You can get the array of parameters passed to the test using [native dependency injection](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection). I see two ways of doing so:

1. Using `ITestResult`:

   ```java
   @Test(groups = {"eventAdmin"}, dataProvider = "EventAdminProvider",
           dataProviderClass = EventAdminCurationDataproviderClass.class)
   public void EventCurationclearFilter(String eventName) throws Exception {
       /* Your test code using `eventName` here. */
   }

   @AfterMethod(groups = {"eventAdmin"})
   public void teardown(ITestResult result) throws Exception {
       String eventName = (String) result.getParameters()[0];
       /* Your teardown code using `eventName` here. */
   }
   ```
2. Using `Object[]`:

   ```java
   @Test(groups = {"eventAdmin"}, dataProvider = "EventAdminProvider",
           dataProviderClass = EventAdminCurationDataproviderClass.class)
   public void EventCurationclearFilter(String eventName) throws Exception {
       /* Your test code using `eventName` here. */
   }

   @AfterMethod(groups = {"eventAdmin"})
   public void teardown(Object[] parameters) throws Exception {
       String eventName = (String) parameters[0];
       /* Your teardown code using `eventName` here. */
   }
   ```

Comment: What happens if there are two @Test methods with different argument lists?

Comment: I believe `teardown` will get called for each which means you'll probably want to find a way to differentiate between which variant. You might find information you can use on `ITestResult`.